# Linq query concatenating two fields

Tags: c#, linq

```
var result = (from u in ctx.Users
              where u.UserId.Equals(id)
              select new
              {
                  FullName = u.LName + ", " + u.FName
              }).ToString();
```

I also tried

```
var result = ctx.Users.Where(u => (u.UserId.Equals(id)))
                      .Select( u => new {FullName=u.LName + ", " + u.FName})
                      .ToString();
```

But both return SQL Select statement, not a full name. Could anyone please help?

Comment: the reason that `ToString` is wrong here, is that your query returns an `IEnumerable` - a collection of items.  Calling ToString on that is bad.

Comment: @Jonesopolis More specifically it's returning an `IQueryable`, thus the reason the OP is getting a SQL query as the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not executing the query. To execute the query, you need to call a special method like `ToList()`, `First()`, `Single()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, etc...

What you are doing is just creating a query. `ToString` would just give you a representation of such query.

Here is an example that uses `First()` to execute the query:

```
var result =
    ctx.Users
        .Where(u => u.UserId.Equals(id))
        .Select(u => u.LName + ", " + u.FName)
        .First();
```

I am using `First` because I assume you are selecting a specific user.

Or for your original code:

```
 var result = (from u in ctx.Users
                      where u.UserId.Equals(id)
                      select new
                      {
                          FullName = u.LName + ", " + u.FName
                      }).First();
```

Comment: Please be aware that you might need guard against the fact that the user might not be there in which case FirstOrDefault would be preferable.

Comment: Do you have a user with the passed `id`?

Comment: You can use `FirstOrDefault`. That would give you `null` if no user was found with the specified condition.

Answer (score 1):

dont use `toString()`

```
 var result = (from u in ctx.Users
                          where u.UserId.Equals(id)
                          select new
                          {
                              FullName = u.LName + ", " + u.FName
                          }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This answer still leaves him with an unexecuted query.

Comment: That does not do anything